# Loss of figure subsection numbers when using mainmatter

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering, lyx, memoir

I recently added `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, etc. with the `\numberwithin` setting for my figures and tables into a document, but now my figures are no longer numbered by subsection on export.  Inside LyX, they still show the correct numbering, but I lose the subsection number upon export.  I am using the memoir package. Here is part of my preamble:

```
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsubsection}
\numberwithin{figure}{subsubsection}
\numberwithin{table}{subsubsection}
```

All numbering was working before inserting the `\...matter` statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, `memoir` does

```
\newcommand\@memmain@floats{%
   \counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
   \counterwithin{table}{chapter}
}
```

which means the figures and tables in the main-matter will be numbered subordinated to the `chapter` counter; to override this, you can add to the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@memmain@floats{%
  \counterwithin{figure}{subsubsection}
  \counterwithin{table}{subsubsection}
}
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsubsection}
\numberwithin{figure}{subsubsection}
\numberwithin{table}{subsubsection}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@memmain@floats{%
  \counterwithin{figure}{subsubsection}
  \counterwithin{table}{subsubsection}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Test chapter}
\vfill% just for the example
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsubsection{Test subsubsection}
\begin{figure}
\caption{test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, since `memoir` internally uses `chngcntr`, you can directly use `\counterwithin` instead of `\numberwithin`:

```
\counterwithin{figure}{subsubsection}
\counterwithin{table}{subsubsection}
```

As a side, personal note, I'd suggest you to reconsidering this numbering schema; having a string so long for the numbers is not very reader-friendly.

Comment: Thank you, Gonzalo. I will try your code. As for the numbering, I'm adapting text from another document that numbered figures/tables by subsection, but it used whole numbers ("105.", "106.") for subsection numbering.

Comment: @jebersole You're welcome. Don't forget that you can accept the answer (if you consider it solved your problem) by clicking the checkmark to its left. For more information: [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).