# Figures should be numbered 4.1.1 and 4.2.1 both numbered 4.1 in list of figures

Tags: numbering, lyx

As I look at my document in LyX, the figure numbering looks like `chapter.section.figurenumber`. However, when a PDF is created the "section" portion of the figure number disappears, and I have multiple figures with the same figure number.

I'm using a custom class created at my University for the thesis that's based on memoir. One of the comments in it is that memoir only numbers section down to section & for most users this isn't enough. So they reset them with

```
\maxsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}
\maxtocdepth{subsubsection}
```

I did some searching and tried

```
\setcounter{lofdepth}{9}
```

to try to get the subsections (being unsure how large the integer should be...), but this did not have any effect after updating the class. There doesn't seem to be a similar

```
\maxlofdepth{subsubsection}
```

type command?

Most of my search finds talked about labeling subfigures not figures in subsections.

Comment: I may have found the answer now thanks to the "related" bar that appeared after posting. I'll give the suggestion that's in
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124036/loss-of-figure-subsection-numbers-when-using-mainmatter?rq=1
a try.

Comment: If what you found works, post an answer to your own question. That will help others who encounter the same problem.

Comment: And, if it doesn't work, we'll likely need the custom class file in order to properly help. Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1):

The link I pasted into my comment above did point me to a solution. I added

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@memmain@floats{%
  \counterwithin{figure}{section}
  \counterwithin{table}{section}
}
\makeatother
```

to the .cls file, and it appears to now be giving me the figure numbers I want.

I just wish I'd found that question/answer before I'd posted my own, so I didn't look quite so inept.

Thanks!

Comment: You look industrious, not inept.